# Where has Umbraco gone?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, umbraco

I installed Umbraco 4.x yesterday on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine with Web PI.  I was playing around with the CWS kit and everything was fine.

I've come back today and can't access the site or see it in IIS(7).  I tried adding to IIS but when I browse I get a 500.19 error.  I've played with the app pool but to no avail.

I guess it's set up to run as a different user but I only have one account on this machine as it's a home PC or maybe it was running under IISExpress?

Any help appreciated.

Edit:

I've added permissions to the folders for IIS and the detail of the 500.19 is now -

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: It was working, and mysteriously the next day it's not?  You're going to have to provide a lot more detail (like what the error really was) if we're going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

500.19 is typically a security issue. You must fix the rights in the folder where you keep Umbraco.

Here is a script I usually run in a console (not powershell) to fix the rights in Umbraco. You must replace the "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco" with the applicationpool name that are running your umbraco site. Ex "IIS APPPOOL\myUmbracoAppPool"

```
icacls . /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls app_code /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)RX
icacls app_browsers /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)RX
icacls app_data /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls bin /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)R
icacls config /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls css /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls data /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls masterpages /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls media /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls python /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls scripts /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls umbraco /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)R
icacls usercontrols /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)R
icacls xslt /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
icacls web.config /grant "IIS APPPOOL\umbraco":(OI)(CI)M
```

Comment: No joy I'm afraid.  I've added config error that I'm getting to the question and am looking around for a fix to that now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing when I installed it originally it was running on IIS Express but I don't know enough about Umbraco to be sure.  Anyway I -

- manually set the site up to run in IIS7, changing the App Pool to .net4
- allowed IUSR permissions on the site directory
- repaired the .Net4 install with "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"

Now it seems to be working.